# EC2, Webserver, and MySQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am about to launch an iOS app that will be communicating with my custom REST API. Right now I am running a single EC2 t2.micro instance running an Apache web server with MySQLi. Before I go ahead and launch it for the public, I want to hear what proper steps should be taken regarding the following.

1. Should I run two separate EC2 instances? One only for the web server and the other to handle only the database?
2. How should I approach setting up the database? Should I still use MySQLi or should I start using Amazon's RDS?
3. In relationship to number two, when the database and/or web server runs out of space, how is this issue handled so that it seamlessly adds space to allow the database/web server to continue growth? I also read something regarding auto-scale.

I will be expecting many requests per minute to my web server and want to take precaution.

Comment: Alec, I notice your acceptance of answers is rather low, and when I've taken a look at a few of your questions where at least one answer is received, there are quite a few that you have not responded to at all. This is one of them. While there is no guideline or obligation to accept answers, we'd have no community here at all if everyone ignored the help they received (or benefited from it but did not vote, reply or accept). If you can go back to old answers you have received and interact with them in _some_ way, your helpers will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to these questions largely depends on the requirements of your application, your budget, and on what you decide to manage vs. what you'd prefer to allow AWS to manage. However, I'll answer these as best I can.

1) Yes. Separating the database from the web server (that is, 2 different EC2 instances) makes sense for a lot of reasons. This will allow you to tailor resources like memory, CPU, etc. to each layer of your application separately. You do not want your web and database competing for the same resources. Additionally, an issue that forces you to take down one (web or database) will not force you to also take down the other. If your database lives on one of the web servers and you need to perform maintenance, your app will effectively become offline, since down goes your database as you perform updates. Also, ideally you would protect your database server within a private subnet in your VPC. If you have the web and database on the same server, they will both be in a public subnet, since you're web will require access to an internet gateway.

2) Depends. If you want to maintain total control of the database server, than use an EC2 instance where you retain operating system control. If you want to take advantage of features like Multi-AZ for high availability or allowing AWS to manage things like updates for you, RDS can be a great option. Cost also plays a role. For things like read-replicas and Multi-AZ, you will pay more, but you are purchasing performance and high availability. Thus, depends on your requirements. You can find the features of RDS here: [RDS Product Details](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/)

3) For anything running on an EC2 instance (database or web) or if you decide to use RDS, you may provision and attach additional storage volumes as necessary. The type of storage you select will depend on the performance requirements, your budget, and the kind of workload you expect your database to face. Amazon provides the storage options available to you as well as a section for adding more storage here: [RDS Storage Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html)

If you are worried about too many requests overwhelming your EC2 t2.micro instance, consider creating an ELB load balancer and setting up an auto-scaling group which will allow you to expand your capacity as necessary while distributing traffic such that no one server gets overwhelmed.